# Таблица ранжирования видеокарт Nvidia по вычислительной производительности CUDA

Tags: python, cuda, nlp, nvidia

Прошу не минусить за вопрос, который "можно погуглить".  Гуглил уже 1.5 часа.
Суть вопроса. Некоторые пакеты распознания текстов и т.п. требуют видеокарту определенного поколения или уровня производительности. Увы - правильного названия не помню.
Это число там  от 3 до 9 примерно... В зависимости от него пакет идет или отказывается работать.  Эта таблица есть на сайте Nvidia.

Но я никак не могу ее найти.
Можете поделиться ссылкой?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute - вот это? там вторая таблица CUDA-Enabled NVIDIA Quadro and NVIDIA RTX

Comment: вот нашел для GTX
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus

Comment: @strawdog  ага! оно! Прошу оформить его как ответ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот слайд по [ссылке](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодарю @strawdog за помощь!

P.S.: Видеокарты с рейтингом менее 6.0  нет смысла покупать для современных пакетов.  Хотя ограничения на сегодня 2023-09-05 в основном 5.